# Duplicate and change a Theme Widget

Tags: themes, widgets

Is there a way (a common one) to duplicate and change a theme widget ?

I'm asking this because, I have this widget that displays the recent news and if we click, it will display ALL news, but I wish to create a new widget that lists the latest articles (posts with a category "articles"), and if we click, that lists ALL articles.

Is there any widget like this that someone knows about ? If not, where should I look at in order to duplicate and change a theme widget ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Widgets [extend the Widget Class](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API#Developing_Widgets), search in the theme code for a class that `extends WP_Widget`. Copy/Paste it, rename it, and change what you'd like.

You can also look in the file `wp-includes/default-widgets.php` and use one of those as a starting point.