# How Can I Duplicate a Widget?

Tags: widgets

By duplicate, I don't me copy the code from a (core) widget and change it a bit. That's [pretty easy](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/20434/duplicate-and-change-a-theme-widget).

I want the push button ability to grab all the settings from a given widget, copy them, stick them into a new widget of the same type, and send that new widget to the same or a new widget area.

Or, better yet: have a widget in another widget area share settings with an already existing widget -- when the parent changes, the other changes.

Are either of those possible?  How?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same Problem with one of my Clients, and found this GREAT soluiton:
[Duplicate Widget](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/duplicate-widget/).

It comes as a new Widget, but has just one option: choose which Widget it should duplicate, and you also see from where it is duplicated (for easy overview where to change the values of the original Widget). Works like a charm, and you have to do every change you make only once for every sidebar.

I suppose this would be your **better yet** solution :)

Answer (score 0):

There's no available feature on the core and you'll be needing a plugin for that. You can check this one :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6GoXWroM5dA

Thanks!